# read file in a folder with their original order in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some files in a folder that are named from 1 to 15. when I use the following code to read all files in a folder, it first read a file with name 10 to 15 and then 1 to 9. but I need to read files in the original order. what should I do to read files in original order from 1 to 15?

```
os.chdir(dir_main) #change directory to downloads folder
files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
fnames_main = [x for x in files_path if x.endswith(".mkv")]
```

my complete code is:

```
def split_vidoe(dir_main,dir_res):
    os.chdir(dir_main) #change directory to downloads folder
    files_path = [os.path.abspath(x) for x in os.listdir()]
    # fnames_main = [x for x in files_path if x.endswith(".mkv")]
    fnames_main = sorted(list(Path(dir_main).iterdir()),
                     key=lambda path: int(path.stem))
    print(len(fnames_main)) 
       
    for i in range(len(fnames_main)):  
        pname1 = (fnames_main[i])
        pname2 = dir_res+str(i+1)+'_'
        
        subprocess.call(['ffmpeg.exe','-i', pname1,'-c:v','libx264','-pix_fmt' ,'yuv420p','-b:v', '8000K', '-bufsize', '8000K' ,'-minrate', '8000K','-maxrate', '8000K', '-x264opts','keyint=60:min-keyint=60','-preset', 'veryfast', '-profile:v', 'high', '-f', 'hls', '-hls_time', '2', '-hls_list_size','0', pname2])
    return
        
current_path=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd());
current_dir = Path.cwd()
all_sub_dir_paths = glob(str(current_dir) + '/*/') # returns list of sub directory paths
all_sub_dir_names = [Path(sub_dir).name for sub_dir in all_sub_dir_paths] 
for i in range(len(all_sub_dir_names)):
    dir_main=current_path+'\\'+all_sub_dir_names[i]
    dir_res=current_path+'\\'+all_sub_dir_names[i]+'\\'+'gop_split'+'\\'
    split_vidoe(dir_main,dir_res)
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @cards' answer:
If you are using python 3.5 or later, you can use the [`pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pathlib.html).

```py
from pathlib import Path

fnames_main = sorted(list(Path(dir_main).iterdir()),
                     key=lambda path: int(path.stem))
```

`sorted`'s `key` keyword arg can take a filter method. In this case, we use `pathlib`'s `.stem` attribute on the `Path` object to get just the filename without the ".mkv" suffix, and sort the list in order by `int`.

Comment: when I used your code it produces this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'gop_split'

Comment: Ah, well, I did not have all of the filenames that are in your directory, if any are strings that cannot be cast to `int`, the function will error like you just discovered. Your question made it seem that all the filenames were like "1.mkv", "2.mkv", etc. You could add a try/except block -- or split the lists via filtering into filenames that are numeric only & filenames that are strings, sort them both separately, then recombine them?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that string ordering is lexicographic, so you need to extract the number part from the name and transformed it to regular int so you can order it by its numeric value, that can be done manually if its just removing the extension or with the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) if its some more complicate thing to extract the numeric part of the name.

Here is a sample with the re module

```
>>> import re
>>> names=sorted(f"video{n}.mkv" for n in range(1,16)) #sample list of names with numbers
>>> names
['video1.mkv', 'video10.mkv', 'video11.mkv', 'video12.mkv', 'video13.mkv', 'video14.mkv', 'video15.mkv', 'video2.mkv', 'video3.mkv', 'video4.mkv', 'video5.mkv', 'video6.mkv', 'video7.mkv', 'video8.mkv', 'video9.mkv']
>>> sorted(names,key=lambda x:int(re.search("([0-9])+",x).group()))
['video1.mkv', 'video2.mkv', 'video3.mkv', 'video4.mkv', 'video5.mkv', 'video6.mkv', 'video7.mkv', 'video8.mkv', 'video9.mkv', 'video10.mkv', 'video11.mkv', 'video12.mkv', 'video13.mkv', 'video14.mkv', 'video15.mkv']
>>>
```

One I personally use, is this variation on the same idea

```
>>> def sort_key_num(name_file:str, str_key=str.lower, nzero:int=3) -> str:
        return str_key( re.sub("([0-9]+)",lambda x: x.group(0).zfill(nzero),name_file) )
>>> sort_key_num("video1.mkv")
'video001.mkv'
>>> sort_key_num("video.mkv")
'video.mkv'
>>> sort_key_num("video 1 - 2.mkv")
'video 001 - 002.mkv'
>>> 
>>> sorted(names, key=sort_key_num)
['video1.mkv', 'video2.mkv', 'video3.mkv', 'video4.mkv', 'video5.mkv', 'video6.mkv', 'video7.mkv', 'video8.mkv', 'video9.mkv', 'video10.mkv', 'video11.mkv', 'video12.mkv', 'video13.mkv', 'video14.mkv', 'video15.mkv']
>>>
```

the *sort_key_num* function here append zeroes to any number (if any) in the string given so the lexicographical order is as expected with the numbers value (and also apply lower to it for good measure )

```
>>> test=["E:\\UGC\\Animation\\9.mkv", "E:\\UGC\\Animation\\1.mkv", "E:\\UGC\\Animation\\10.mkv"]
>>> sorted(test)
['E:\\UGC\\Animation\\1.mkv', 'E:\\UGC\\Animation\\10.mkv', 'E:\\UGC\\Animation\\9.mkv']
>>> sorted(test, key=sort_key_num)
['E:\\UGC\\Animation\\1.mkv', 'E:\\UGC\\Animation\\9.mkv', 'E:\\UGC\\Animation\\10.mkv']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The strings follow the lexicographic order so you need to cast to integer. To get rid of the file extension you can use `os.path.splitext`

- with `sort`: return a generator

```
fnames_main = sorted([x for x in files_path if x.endswith(".mkv")], key=lambda path: int(os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0])])
```

- with `list.sort`: works directly on the memory address, return none

```
fnames_main = [x for x in files_path if x.endswith(".mkv")]
fnames_main.sort( key=lambda path: int(os.path.splitext(os.basename(path))[0]))
```

**Remark**:

- to get rid of any path dependencies such as `\`, `.` call first `basename` and then split per file extension with `splitext`
- **EDIT** to make it less universal and using the fact that the list is filtered already per file extension it can be rewritten in a more "friendly" way as:

  ```
  fnames_main.sort( key=lambda path: int(os.basename(path)[:-len('.mkv')]))
  ```

Comment: I am a little confused. what does it mean? my files has .mkv format (1.mkv,2.mkv,...,15.mkv). how do I use your answer?

Comment: @david The point is that you need to sort the list in the way you expect. The key here is that the file names are strings. So `"10.mkv"` comes before `"2.mkv"` because that's how string comparison works. You can use the `key` argument to `sorted` to define how to sort the list rather than using the default string ordering.

Comment: @david I mixed the command of `os.path`, it was `os.path.splitext` and not `os.path.basename`

Comment: @cards when I used your code, it produced this error:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'E:\\UGC\\Animation\\1'

Comment: all your mkv are of the form, number(s).mkv? Another possibility is that your files are not in the same folder of your script so it make int(path) which is an error. Does make sense for you? Meanwhile I try to fix the 2nd option

Comment: yes, 1.mkv,2.mkv,....15.mkv. I put my complete code above.

Comment: I think the `os.chdir` gave some side effects concerning the path